# Problem with Sign-in to Nativescript app with google provider

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin, nativescript-firebase

I try to use google provider to log in to my angular nativescript app. My web app works properly, for mobile added SHA-1 to firebase console.

I have two problems:

1. After try to log in with google provider firebaseWebApi.auth().onAuthStateChanged not fired (login function returns User properly).
2. When Sign-in with google provider is not possible I try to simply log in with firebaseWebApi.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(), but I have an error message: "Logging in the user failed. com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException: This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."

It's weird because without trying to log in with google provider, signInWithEmailAndPassword works properly.

```
  public async startLoginGoogle(): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    const user = await firebase.login({
      type: firebase.LoginType.GOOGLE
    });
    // user with getIdTokenResult() is available here
    return  user.getIdTokenResult();
  }

  firebaseWebApi.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => {
    // nothing
    subject.next(user);
  });
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean, after canceling the login process from Google log-in page if you try login with email / password directly it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, after restarting the app it's fine again, but not if I try to log in with email/password directly after unsuccessfully log in with google provider.

Comment: Can you setup a sample project to demonstrate the issue.